# How to take a range as a variable in Rust?

Tags: indexing, rust, range

I'm not sure what type and how to use a range variable in Rust. Looking around I couldn't find an example of how they worked when passed. Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html), [`RangeTo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeTo.html), [`RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html) or [`RangeFull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html):

```
use std::ops::Range;

fn foo(r: Range<i32>) {}

fn main() {
    foo(0..10);
}
```

Each range type is parameterized with a concrete type.

Comment: Ah guess i found some old documentation i saw something with std::indexing::Range and was confused. Much appreciated.